# Set limited range to scoreboard

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Do anyone know any way to set a limited range to the scoreboard?

I want to avoid that players who aren't involved in a minigame, but are in the same world, get tracked on the scoreboard.

Answer (score 0):

After the `@p` target selector, you can add a range of arguments to further modify what players are selected. Full details can be found on the Minecraft Wiki page [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands).

Then go to the 'target selectors' section.

In terms of answering your question specifically, you probably want something like:

```
/scoreboard players add @p[r=10] Minigame 1
```

This, of course, assumes that all players in the game will be within 10 blocks of the command-block when the command is run. Alternatively, you can use the dx/dy/dz volume selectors to target players in a more specific box area. More info on how to use this (and other options) can be found on the linked page.